# Disable drop down options based on selected value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am having a drop down list contains values like fb-test, fb-testing, tw-test, tw-testing as follows. I am trying to disable the options in the following way.

1. When the user select fb-test from the drop down, the fb-testing should disable.
2. When the user select tw-testing or tw-test, the option contains 'tw' should disable.

This is the HTML mark-up I am using:

```
<select id="wpri-profile">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="fb-test">fb-test</option>
    <option value="fb-testing">fb-testing</option>
    <option value="tw-test">tw-test</option>
    <option value="tw-testing">tw-testing</option>                  
</select>
```

This is the code I am trying:

```
$('#wpri-profile').on('change',function(){
    $(this).find('option').prop('disabled',false);  
    var val = $(this).val();
    var prof = val.split("-");
    alert(prof[0]);
    $(this).find('option[value="'+prof[0]+'"]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one and working as you expect,

```js
$('#wpri-profile').on('change',function(){
$(this).find('option').prop('disabled',false);  
var val = $(this).val();
var prof = val.split("-");
//alert(prof[0]);
  
$(this).find('option[value*='+prof[0]+']').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="wpri-profile">
                <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                <option value="fb-test">fb-test</option>
                <option value="fb-testing">fb-testing</option>
                <option value="tw-test">tw-test</option>
                <option value="tw-testing">tw-testing</option>                  
            </select>
```

Comment: When selecting tw-testing it wont hiding tw-test from options. Please help me.

Comment: Sure, let me check

Comment: Done, please check now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the value starting with selector `^`:

```
$('#wpri-profile').on('change',function(){
   $(this).find('option').prop('disabled',false);  
   var val = $(this).val();
   var prof = val.split("-");

   // starting with selector shall do it
   $(this).find('option[value^="'+prof[0]+'"]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

`input[value *=tw]` it will match out all the value starting with `tw`

```js
$('#wpri-profile').on('change',function(){
$(this).find('option').prop('disabled',false);  
var val = $(this).val();
var prof = val.split("-");
alert(prof[0]);
  
$(this).find('option[value *='+val+']').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="wpri-profile">
                <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                <option value="fb-test">fb-test</option>
                <option value="fb-testing">fb-testing</option>
                <option value="tw-test">tw-test</option>
                <option value="tw-testing">tw-testing</option>                  
            </select>
```

Comment: When tw-test being selected, I want to disable the tw-testing too from the options. Please help me any solution.